# ignored-qualifiers only with void* typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

This works fine

```
const void* getObjHandle() {
 return (const void*)hdl;
}
```

But the below gives ignored-qualifiers warning.

> error: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
>   [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]

```
typedef void* objHandle;
const objHandle getObjHandle() {
 return (const objHandle)hdl;
}
```

The below one gives an invalid static_cast error along with the ignored-qualifiers warning

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const Object*’ to type ‘const
>   objHandle {aka void* const}’

```
typedef void* objHandle;
const objHandle getObjHandle() {
 return static_cast<const objHandle>(hdl);
}
```

The below one works again

```
typedef void* objHandle;
const void* getObjHandle() {
 return static_cast<const void*>(hdl);
}
```

hdl is a const pointer to an object I am getting from another helper inside getObjHandle().
Why are these warnings/errors coming? How can I get rid of them without getting rid of the typedefs.

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what your question is? There seem to be only factual statements.

Comment: `const objHandle` is interpreted as `void *const`.

Comment: Please stop downvoting ~good~ not terrible questions.

Comment: Pointer to const something vs. const pointer to something. That pretty much says it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two are not the same due to how C++ qualifiers are syntactically defined:

```
using one = const T*;

using pointer = T*
using const_pointer = const pointer;
```

The latter const is applied to the outside of type `pointer`, which is the pointer type, not the type pointed to.

Note you can always put `const` after the type you need it applied to, which is actually the most robust and confusion-free yet awkward in the common "const ref" situation:

```
using pointer_to_const = T const *;

using pointer = T*;
using const_pointer = pointer const;
```

Here, you can immediately see through substitution that `const_pointer` ends up as `T* const` which is not the same as `pointer_to_const`.

There is no way to "inject" a const inside an previously defined type alias, you can only slap it on the outside (i.e. right side) of the aliased type.

Comment: That cleared it up. Thanks! I didn't realize it was a const placement issue. Is there a better way to "typedef" void pointers ?

Comment: @Saynb: Yes: don't. And while you're at it, don't use `void*`. We have templates for a reason ;).